# Restore graph in TensorFlow - Restore the value in a Tensor

Tags: python-3.x, search, tensorflow, neural-network, restore

I have build an Artificial Neural Networks to predict values ​​for life insurance data. When I restore the graph i can import my predict tensor for see my value.

```
sess = tf.Session()
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt.meta')
new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
inputs = graph.get_tensor_by_name("inputs:0")
predict_restore = graph.get_tensor_by_name("predicted:0")
train_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\...\tensorflow-1.3.1\tensorflow\train_titanic.csv")
train_predict_restore = train_data.drop(["Survived"], axis=1)
feed_dict={inputs:train_predict_restore}
prob =sess.run(predict_restore,feed_dict)
```

In the feed_dict I put the attribute of client in tensor inputs. Now I want to build a function that inputs the attributes of the customer, I go to look for their respective probability of survival (prob). There is a function in tensorflow to search one or more value in a tensor? (in my situation tensor inputs)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ***train_predict_restore*** is in the shape of [num_customers attributes]. Therefore, ***train_predict_restore[i]*** represents the ***ith*** certain customer  .

You can do something like this,

```
feed_dict={inputs:[train_predict_restore[i]]}//changed train_predict_restore to [train_predict_restore[i]]
prob =sess.run(predict_restore,feed_dict)
```

Here, the output is the probability values for the ***ith*** customer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My issue is not extract the probability by train_predict_restore, but  build a function that inputs the attributes of the customer, I go to look for their respective probability.  I put this attributes in my first session in a Inputs tensor. Maybe I can use the LookUp function by i don't understand how it work.